# aggregate rows as jsonb in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

```
key            | value            | col
----------------------------------------
color          | red              | g1
color          | blue             | g2
contrast       | {'l':123456}     | g1
setting        | srnew            | g2
contrast       | {'s':123456}     | g1    

key        | value                    | col
---------------------------------------------
color      | ['red']                  | g1
color      | ['blue']                 | g2
contrast   | [{'l':123456}, {'s':456}]| g1
setting    | ['srnew']                | g2
```

How would I aggregate the first table into the second table?

Column `value` is of type jsonb. I want the result column `value` to be jsonb too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) do group by concat then `array_to_json` to json array.

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(value)) 
FROM t
group by key,col
```

Comment: No problem glad to help

Comment: i replaced the `array_to_json(array_agg(_))` with `jsonb_agg`. because i wanted a jsonb as the column type.